# how do i solve the dependency problem? in ubuntu 18.04 lts

Tags: package-management, dpkg, dependencies

**strong text**when i try to install any software package,at the end i am shown a bunch of dependency errors as below:

```
 dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     python3
     apparmor
     snapd
     passwd
     adduser
     openssh-client
     dirmngr
     gnupg
     gpg-wks-client
     udev
     systemd
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

i tried resolving it and i am now stuck here:
**i am getting this error:
(this the output)

```
 najeeb@najeeb-Vostro-3480:~$ sudo apt-get install stacer
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    stacer is already the newest version (1.1.0-1bionic).
    You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     aspell : Depends: dictionaries-common (> 0.40) but it is not going to be installed
     aspell-en : Depends: dictionaries-common (>= 0.49.2) but it is not going to be installed
     dictionaries-common-dev : Depends: dictionaries-common (>= 1.22.3) but it is not going to be installed
     hunspell-en-us : Depends: dictionaries-common (>= 0.10) but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).**
```

and the output of :"**$ apt-cache policy stacer aspell python3 systemd"** is:

```
  najeeb@najeeb-Vostro-3480:~$ apt-cache policy stacer aspell python3 systemd
stacer:
  Installed: 1.1.0-1bionic
  Candidate: 1.1.0-1bionic
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.0-1bionic 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oguzhaninan/stacer/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
aspell:
  Installed: 0.60.7~20110707-4ubuntu0.1
  Candidate: 0.60.7~20110707-4ubuntu0.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.60.7~20110707-4ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.60.7~20110707-4 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
python3:
  Installed: 3.6.7-1~18.04
  Candidate: 3.6.7-1~18.04
  Version table:
 *** 3.6.7-1~18.04 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.6.5-3 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
systemd:
  Installed: 237-3ubuntu10.45
  Candidate: 237-3ubuntu10.45
  Version table:
 *** 237-3ubuntu10.45 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     237-3ubuntu10.38 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     237-3ubuntu10 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

and when i try the command "apt --fix-broken install" i  still get the same error.
kindly help me out!

Comment: `apt list --installed | grep python` edit your question for output and `lsb_release -rd` too please.

Comment: that is the entire output i am getting should shorten it up?

Comment: najeeb@najeeb-Vostro-3480:~$ apt list --installed | grep python

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution (.........)and Description: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release: 18.04

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy stacer aspell python3 systemd` to the question.

Comment: i have added the output of  "apt-cache policy stacer aspell python3 systemd" in the question , please check it out.

Comment: i have added the output please check it . i urgently need to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a broken Ubuntu install.

I know that this may not be the most elegant solution, but the best way to resolve this issue, is by simply reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: how do i reinstall? and will i loose all my data after i reinstall?

Comment: Just go through the same process you went through when you originally installed Ubuntu, and choose “Erase Ubuntu and Reinstall” when you get to “Installation Type”. And yes, it will erase your data that is on your Ubuntu partition (so you should back up your data before you do this).

Comment: i have updated my question . please go through it once.

Comment: Have you tried a wipe-and-reinstall (which I suggested in my answer) yet?

Comment: i reinstalled and everything works perfectly now! thanks